# MongoDB - Is it possible to conditionally merge a new document in an db.collection.aggregate() query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given a collection which stores ranges of integers in each document

```
{
    "begin": 20,
    "end": 340
}
```

Is it possible to use a `db.collection.aggregate()` query (probably with `$match`, `$count`, and `$merge`) to conditionally insert a new document in which the begin and end don't overlap with any of the existing documents?

Comment: you can upsert with necessary conditions. Is aggregation mandatory?

Comment: I don't think aggregation would be useful, but you might be able to use a transaction to atomically query the collection and conditionally insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it is not possible with an aggregation query.

This is possible to accomplish with an upsert and conditions (filters) as @Dheemanth Bhat suggested in the comments, using [`db.collection.updateOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) or [`db.collection.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/).

In my case I wasn't able to use this because there was an additional requirement around tracking an incrementing identifier. What I ended up doing was to split it up into two queries: one which checks for any overlap, and the other which inserts the document.